# what are the sizes of the ocarinas

Tags: tuning, instruments, beginner, ocarina

I have been trying to find the sizes for every ocarina (1C to 7C), width and height of the chamber .The only one I can find was because a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJVS3uPj24I&list=PLp7sx_rc3suLvsOOxka0UBjWpKAI7lF9m&index=7). I am asking this because I want make my own ocarinas and I don't want to make every imaginable size, if there is someone who could help me or point me in the right direction. I really don't know if this site is the best place to start but I have to start somewhere.

Comment: I might know nothing, but I'd say this: how many numbers are there between 0 and 1? You could make your own ocarinas, no matter their size or extension, I doubt anybody would ever tell you "oh, that's not a proper ocarina!".

Comment: You might find these instructions for building a (tenor) ocarina interesting and/or helpful: https://www.instructables.com/How-To-Make-A-Wooden-Ocarina/.

Comment: @Aaron great site!, only 6 more to go

Comment: You can certainly build one any physical size, thus changing the base note.  If you're really interested, I recommend reading a bit about Helmholtz resonators to learn how to set the finger-hole sizes.   You could create any scale you want!

Comment: BTW, depending on the material you want to deal with, there are lots of models on Thingiverse.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft incredible, did not know about this, thank you very much!